Azimuthal symmetry in the flow past a spherical obstacle
For a flow passing a spherical obstacle, I don't really understand why the azimuthal term
$$\dfrac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \theta} \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \varphi^2}$$
of $\vec{v} = - \nabla \phi$ is $0$.
Does it mean that the velocity is constant along the azimuthal axis? I can't visualize it.

It is due to symmetry of the flow.

I can't see why there is no symmetry along the theta axis if the flow is "flat".

I have no idea what you’re referring to.

I don't understand why the symmetry of the flow ensure that only the azimuthal term is 0.

Choose the axis of the sphere such that it is parallel to the far field flow velocity.  Then, the longitudinal component of the flow is zero everywhere.

If I understood correctly the flow will past the sphere from the "top" and "bottom" but not from the "side".

Do you think it really matters if it is a s sphere?

It is not what I meant.  I said that in the sense that there is a "side" where the flow will not past, otherwise the flow will not be constant for theta nor phi.

Are you saying that the coordinate system you choose to employ affects the actual fluid flow?

No, not really. I'm just trying to understand why the longitudinal component of the flow is zero. Near the sphere, I don't see how the longitudinal component is zero if the flow "wrap" the sphere. Clearly, the phi component and the theta component are not constant throughout the path.

The only way that the longitudinal component of the flow is zero is if there is a "side" where the flow doesn't past as I said earlier. For instance, the flow past the obstacle from the top and the bottom, but not from the "side" (there is no movement in the phi coordinate) or if you prefer a kind of rotation. I'm not sure why you mention the coordinates system, since we are talking about spherical coordinates with the phi coordinate equal to zero. For instance, this diagram (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzUEv2hjvAM) seems to corroborate what I say.

In the video, the flow is in the positive z direction, and there is no component of flow velocity in the phi direction.

Exactly. Basically, this was my initial question. The azimuthal term is zero because the flow velocity is zero in the phi direction. Also, is this what azimuthal symmetry means?

The axisuthal velocity is zero  because of the symmetry.  The flow doesn't know whether it should increase or decrease with phi, so it stays on a line of constant phi.

The argument is not azimutal/rotational symmetry. It is not sufficient to guarantee that $v_\phi=0$. A sufficient symmetry is invariance by plane reflection about any plane containing the axis of symmetry. Since velocity is a vector (not a pseudo-vector), this forces the the vector to be in that plane.
Note that this set of plane reflection generates the rotation group, so they are sufficient to deduce that the velocity field is of the form:
$$
u=u_r(r,\theta)e_r+u_\theta(r,\theta)e_\theta
$$
and so the potential is of the form $\phi(r,\theta)$ as expected.
